# how to covert images to video in android

Tags: android, video

In my application I am taking screen shots, later I want to convert these screen shots to video like 3gp format.

How can one do that?

Comment: i am trying to convert the list of images into a video file as you tried. Did you got it working. Looking a your response. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked for any encoding libraries to date within Android, but, you can surely try combining both Xuggle and a port of ffmpeg to Android altogether.

You will need to compile ffmpeg using Android's NDK
http://odroid.foros-phpbb.com/t338-ffmpeg-compiled-with-android-ndk

Then you can try to use Xuggle Wrapper API within your app to make use of it.

http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/

You will then have to check if the current build has support for the 3gp format, but I guess libavccodec can do the job.

Hope that helps.